# how to make React app scroll to a specific component on a newly rendered page providing its URL

Tags: reactjs

React app scroll to a specific component on a newly rendered page providing its URL doesn't work using `smooth-scroll` `npm` .it's stuck on middle reaching to component in url.for eg I have `url` `http://localhost:3000/#contact` its stop on this middle .

**APP.js:**

```
export default function App() {
  useEffect(() => {
    if (window.location.hash) {
      let elem = document.getElementById(window.location.hash.slice(1));
      if (elem) {
        elem.scrollIntoView({ behavior: "smooth" });
      }
    } else {
      window.scrollTo({ top: 0, left: 0, behavior: "smooth" });
    }
  }, [window.location.hash]);
 <div className="main-container"> 
   
      <Header/>
      <Home />  
      <About />
      <Blog />
      <Contact />
      <Footer />
      <ScrollToTop />
</div>
)}
contact page

 <div id="contact" className="newContact">
      <h2 style={{ marginbottom: "12px" }}>Contact us</h2>
</div>
```

What I am expecting when user type that `url` it should go to that component.

Answer (score 0):

Solution is to use the react-scroll library

Install react-scroll

Import the Link component from react-scroll in your component file:

```
import { Link } from "react-scroll";
```

Replace the anchor tags () in your navigation links with the Link component:

```
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li>
      <Link to="home" smooth={true} duration={500}>
        Home
      </Link>
    </li>
    <li>
      <Link to="about" smooth={true} duration={500}>
        About
      </Link>
    </li>
    <li>
      <Link to="blog" smooth={true} duration={500}>
        Blog
      </Link>
    </li>
    <li>
      <Link to="contact" smooth={true} duration={500}>
        Contact
      </Link>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

the to prop of the Link component should be the ID of the target component.

In your useEffect hook, use the scrollToTop() function from react-scroll to scroll to the top of the page when there's no hash in the URL:

```
import { scrollToTop } from "react-scroll";

useEffect(() => {
  if (window.location.hash) {
    let elem = document.getElementById(window.location.hash.slice(1));
    if (elem) {
      elem.scrollIntoView({ behavior: "smooth" });
    }
  } else {
    scrollToTop({ duration: 500 });
  }
}, [window.location.hash]);
```

You can also pass a duration prop to the scrollToTop() function to control the speed of the scrolling animation.

Comment: i think above code didnot work why?

Comment: Try react-scroll as suggested in this answer

Comment: tried no thing happens

Comment: Is the ID of your div and the one in URL are same?